# how to make own android app looks fine?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have samsung sgs2 with official ics. Google apps look fine on my android(gmail, maps, etc), they use native ics widgets, but my own apps use samsung's widgets. How to specify in config files in projects, that I want to use native android ics widgets?
I mean widgets are buttons, dialogs, radiobuttons.

Answer (score 1):

The default applications use Holo Theme. To apply it to your application add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

to your application tag in manifest. More information on this can be found here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just a theme issue.

Try setting your application to the Android Holo Theme.

Example here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html